# List of Characters that are equivalent in unicode collation

Tags: mysql, unicode, collation

MySQL complains that these 2 characters are essensially the same word

横浜市保土ヶ谷区

横浜市保土ケ谷区

Notice that the only different is the charactger
ヶ
and character 
ケ

The bottom one is slightly bigger but it's essentially the same character. At least if I set the collation in mySQL to UTF8 and uses this as IDs, my SQL will complaints that the same character has been used as IDs before.

I want a function that will map those 2 different character into their most standard version.

Where can I found such complete lists?

Comment: They're actually rather different. ケ is the regular katakana letter *ke*, usually used only together with other katakana letters as in カラオケ *karaoke*. ヶ is most often used in place names and a few other contexts and typically pronounced *ka* or *ga*, in the above example *hodogaya*. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ヶ). Using ケ in the above context is not technically incorrect, but uncommon. So "mapping to their most standard version" doesn't make a lot of sense without extensive context analysis.

Comment: in any case, utf-8 unicode claim that the 2 are essensially the same. They are actually names of cities and name of cities must be unique (because I use the name of the city also as city ids). So how do I get a table of list of characters that's essentially the same?

Comment: I just manually translate this. Not many characters are like this.

Comment: What do you mean with MySQL "complains"? Can you be more specific - what are you trying to do, what error do you get?

Comment: I used those as IDs and IDs must be unique. MySQL complaints that under UTF8 collation, those characters are the same characters.